# python command line program passed in as string throwing error

Tags: python, cmd

My directory structure is kind of like:

```
A -|
   |_ B.py
C -|
   |_ D.py
```

while running python I am inside C directory
I need to execute B.py from cmd with -c option
something like this: 
`cd C:\something\C
C:\something\C> python -c "import ..\A\B"`

But the import B is throwing error `"SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation charcter"`

Please find the screenhot below

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAnq4.png)

Actually I need to execute some function inside B.py module so need -c option. The whole command looks like this:

`C:\something\C> python -c "import ..\A\B; B.sm_fun()"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you try changing the "import ..\A\B" to "import ..\\A\\B" or to "import ../A/B" ?

Comment: @warped I tried "import ..\\A\\B" but its showing error as `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Why not just `python ..\A\B.py`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard actually I need to call & execute some function inside the B.py module. For this reason I need to call it with the -c option only. I edited the ques. and added this info. Apologies for that.

Comment: `import ..A.B`, python do not take the slashes

Comment: Tried this also ! `python -c "import ..A.B; B.sm_func()"` , but still getting the same error as `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at first dot position i.e. before A !